# Restrict users in django

Tags: python, django, panel

I have a panel to manage posts by admin or the users that are admin.
How can I restrict panel and display it only for admins not other users that register in system.

### View:

```
class IndexView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'panel/index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["posts"] = Post.objects.all()
        context["counter"] = self.post_counter(context["posts"])
        return context

    def post_counter(self, posts):
        postNumber = 0
        for post in posts:
            postNumber +=1

        return postNumber
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are having CBV you can use the PermissionMixin and then specific the permission. Something like this :

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin

class MyView(PermissionRequiredMixin, View):
   permission_required = ("is_staff", "is_superuser", )
   ....
```

Reference : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.PermissionRequiredMixin

If you would be having function based view then you can use `@staff_member_required`

Something like this :

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required

@staff_member_required
def my_view(request):
   ...
```

Reference and further read : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.views.decorators.staff_member_required

Answer (score 1):

You can create view's mixin which requires that the user be an admin:

```
class AdminRequiredMixin:
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_staff:
            return redirect(WHERE_YOU_WANT)
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the template, you can do that by directly checking the user

```
{% if user.is_superuser %}
    <p>I'm an admin.</p>
{% else %}
    <p>I'm an user.</p>
{% endif %}
```